# BIT Making in permutation generation

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am learning about TSP and understand it quite well , but i could not understand How Bit masking can be used to generate all permutation.
If i am 3 citites so i will find the cost as:

```
0 1 2 3
0 1 3 2
0 2 1 3
0 2 3 1
0 3 1 2
0 3 2 1
```

or:

```
                               g(0,{1,2,3})

             /                      |                \

    g(1,{2,3})                g(2,{1,3})            g(3,{1,2})

    /         \             /          \             |       \

g(2,{3})   g(3,{2})     g(1,{3})     g(3,{1})    g(1,{2})    g(2,{1})  

  /            |            |           |           |             |    
 0             0            0           0           0             0
g(3,null)   g(2,null)    g(3,null)   g(1,null)   g{2,null)    g(1,null)
```

How bit masking is used in this

Comment: What does "bit masking" mean exactly?

Comment: means there are n cities we use 1<<n number to represent all cities and arrive at all combination

Comment: So you mean a dynamic programming solution with bit masks?

Comment: @user2040251 yes sir please explain me that would be really helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a dynamic programming solution with `O(2^n * n^2)` time and `O(2^n * n)` space complexity which uses bit masks.

Let's assume that `f(mask, last)` is the shortest path that goes for all cities in the `mask` which starts in `0` city and ends in the `last` city(`last` must be in the `mask`).

The base case is simple: `f(1, 0) = 0`(it corresponds to the case when the only city we have visited so far is the start city).

Transitions:

```
 for cur not in mask
      for last = 0 ... n - 1
          f(mask or 2^cur, cur) = min(f(mask or 2^cur, cur), f(mask, last) + dist(last, cur))
```

The answer is `min(f(2^n - 1, last) + dist(last, 0) for last = 1 ... n - 1)`

Comment: [Code](http://ideone.com/tYdrK8) I could not understand how making  is working in the `compute` function

Comment: @user4392540 This code is sotra hard to read, but in general it does the same thing as described in my answer, it just uses recursion.

Comment: why you loop last = 0 to n-1 please explain

Comment: @user4392540 We have to return to the start city and we could finish in any of 1 ... n - 1 cities. So we try all options and choose the best one.

Comment: also explain the first loop `for cur not in mask`